# OBIEE 12C changing default font size

Tags: obiee

I'm currently on a project using OBIEE 12C and the customer wants to change the default font size, but we don't know how to do this. We've found this link: https://biskills.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/increasing-the-font-size-of-the-dashboard-pagetab-in-obiee/ but we have multiple items of the file they are talking about. What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is deploy a custom skin, that you can customise. The authoritative instruction for this is in the application documentation, under [Customizing the Oracle BI Web User Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/biee/BIESG/GUID-237D613D-CC0D-464D-BBC2-9A223CD12567.htm).

The approach in the page you have linked to of changing the skins in-place is not recommended as future patches may overwrite your changes – especially with 12c moving to EAR based skins. Off the top of my head the location of those files doesn't look right either, but I may be wrong.